# How to find time difference between two dates using oracle sql?

Tags: oracle, date, date-difference

I have table called `C_Order`. It has column  `UPDATED` and `CREATED`. The data type both are `Date`, one sample data

`CREATED` = `TO_DATE('2015-09-02 14:03:56', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`
`UPDATED` = `TO_DATE('2015-09-02 14:07:19', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`

I need to get difference between those two dates in terms of days, hours, and minutes.

I tried using `DateDiff` but it won't work, also I subtracted the dates but what I got is just something like 0,00123. How can I make the result in terms of days, hours, and minutes?

Comment: There is no `datediff` in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Days

```
select date_col1 - date_col2 from table_name;
```

Hours

```
select
    24 * (date_col1 - date_col2) 
table_name;
```

Minutes

```
select (date_col1 - date_col2) * 1440
from table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cast both columns to a `timestamp` the result of subtracting one from the other is an [`interval`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#i78291)

An interval represents a duration in days, hours, minutes and seconds.

```
select cast(created as timestamp) - cast(updated as timestamp) 
from the_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, here it is:

```
SELECT to_number( to_char(to_date('1','J') +
              ("UPDATED" - CREATED), 'J') - 1)  days,
               to_char(to_date('00:00:00','HH24:MI:SS') +
               ("UPDATED" - CREATED, 'HH24:MI:SS') time
        FROM C_ORDER;
```